# how to get sum of amount using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using below code for getting every record total amount from the table, but it's not getting proper results.
It is getting single record from the table but I need total records from my table

```
SELECT 
    ur.user_id, ur.user_fullname, ur.user_status, ur.user_mobileno,
    sum(pr.pre_amount) AS achivedamt 
FROM users_register ur 
INNER JOIN prepostings pr 
ON ur.user_id=pr.user
```

Comment: You need to use GROUP BY statement

Comment: show your query result and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bellow code, i hope solve your problem.

```
SELECT ur.user_id,ur.user_fullname,ur.user_status,ur.user_mobileno,
sum(pr.pre_amount) AS achivedamt 
FROM users_register ur INNER JOIN prepostings pr 
ON ur.user_id=pr.user group by ur.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a GROUP BY to your query:

```
SELECT 

    ur.user_id
    ,ur.user_fullname
    ,ur.user_status
    ,ur.user_mobileno
    ,sum(pr.pre_amount) AS achivedamt 
    FROM users_register ur 
    INNER JOIN prepostings pr ON ur.user_id=pr.user

    GROUP BY ur.user_id
```